# CustomValidator cannot validate text value of a link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I have a link button which is dynamically created in code behind. And its text value can be empty or not. I want to validate the text value of the link button when I submit my form.

So, in code behind, I create the link button and its CustomValidator like this:

```
Protected WithEvents lnkBtn As LinkButton
Protected WithEvents cusVal As CustomValidator

lnkBtn = New LinkButton()
lnkBtn.ID = "lnkButton"
lnkBtn.Text = "The Input Text"   //This value is dynamically assigned to a value.
                                 //And it can be empty.

cusVal = New CustomValidator()
cusVal.ID = "reqValidator"
cusVal.ValidationGroup = "FormEditGroup"
cusVal.ErrorMessage = "The text of lnkButton cannot be empty"
cusVal.Display = ValidatorDisplay.None
cusVal.ControlToValidate = "lnkButton"
AddHandler cusVal.ServerValidate, AddressOf cusVal_ServerValidate
```

The cusVal_ServerValidate event is defined as below:

```
Private Sub cusVal_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value.Trim) Then
        args.IsValid = False
    Else
        args.IsValid = True
    End If
End Sub
```

HOWEVER, there is an exception in runtime.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
>
> Additional information: Control 'lnkButton' referenced by the
>   ControlToValidate property of 'reqValidator' cannot be validated.

Is there anyway to validate the text of the link button? Or where I should change my code to archive my goal?

Comment: Why would you want to validate the text of the LinkButton? You are the one who is seting it's text in the first place... Anyways, a LinkButton cannot be validated, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VDWWD: The text of the link button in my project is dynamically assigned to a value. And it can be empty. I need to validate it before submitting the form.